# Copy entire row of active cell to one row down IF row is empty

Tags: excel, vba, copy

Relatively new to VBA, so apologies if this is a poorly phrased question:

How can I set up a macro so that it will copy the entire row containing the active cell to the next empty row down?

Potential complications:

- All data is being entered in a pivot table due to other functions
- One column auto-calculates, does that count as not being empty?
- I managed to make a macro copy to the next row down, but it will
  overwrite that row as it stands.

(I know I could copy paste the row but I'm making a very large spreadsheet for other people who want to fill it as fast as possible.)

A brief description of what I have so far:

```
Sub CopyDown()
'
' CopyDown Macro
' duplicate current row
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'
    If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow) Then
    'This part works
    ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    'This part works

    End If
End Sub
```

Advice would be appreciated, even if it's just the right keywords to search for this type of function.

Comment: Side note: You want to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code. Doing so will also make your problem easier to solve

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad , thanks, but the entire purpose of this macro is to copy the entire current row down to the next empty row, I'm not sure how I could avoid using select and still be able to have this work for any row? (All the alternatives I've seen involve setting a range. this is a workbook that will log thousands of queries solved by 7+ different users.)

Comment: There are several questions here about finding the last row. Did you go to the link I provided?

Comment: Yes, the problem lies in understanding how I can get around the examples, which list the ranges as things like "A1:B10" when I want the range of cells being copy and pasted to be "A17:X17" when the currently highlighted cell is in row 17, and "A223:X223" when the currently highlighted cell is in row 223.

Comment: Tried a couple other setups I found:
>Dim x as Integer
>x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
>Activecell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
>ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(1,1).Offset(1,0).Activate

Comment: Can't quite copy the other setups I've found, but two examples of "jump to first empty cell" https://excelribbon.tips.net/T006197_Jumping_to_the_Start_of_the_Next_Data_Entry_Row.html

And "find the last non-blank cell in column A, offset 1 down" https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/find-last-row-column-cell/

Have both not worked when I substituted them for line 3 of the "this part works" segment.